The meaning of the word "comprise" in a patent application
If I say "The widget comprises A, B, and C". Does this exclude the possibility of D and E being part of the widget?

Are you referring to claims or specification? I wouldn't use "comprising"/"comprises" in a specification myself.

Actually, I was more thinking about the specifications.

The specification does not need to be as formal as the claims, so I think it's possible to just write "has". E.g. "In accordance with the Xth embodiment, the widget has an A. [further describe A]. Further in accordance with the Xth embodiment, the widget has a B. [further describe B]." etc. Also check that the nonce word (here "widget") is not unduly limiting.

No - patent claiming 101: comprising is open ended adding other things will
not avoid infringement.
Consisting of is close ended. Then there is substantially consisting of, etc.
